# Progressive tense with a fixed date

Tags: past-tense, continuous

> Rhythm will be closing permanently from 5pm on 21st December. Many thanks to all our customers for your support over the years, for our market stall, monthly mail-order catalogue, and online. If you have any final orders, please send them as soon as possible, and we'll do our best to get them to you before we close.

Why will be closing   why no will be closed and there is a date.Can we have a progressive tense with a precise date

Comment: Sorry but you are thanking your clients for your stuff?? Yes, the progressive is fine but you can also use just "will close". We thank **our customers*** for their support. Many thanks to all of you for your support.

Comment: It should also be *at 5pm*, not *from 5pm*.

Comment: It's incorrect, that's why.  There are various other ways to say it, just not this one.  Even native speakers sometimes say strange things.

Comment: @Lambie: I parse this as "for your support ... for our market stall etc."

Comment: @ColinFine The pronouns must be: you/your or our/their. But not: our/your. We thank our allies for your support? it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Andrew, I find "will be closing at ..." completely normal.

Using a progressive form with *will* makes it a bit tentative. There probably isn't anything tentative about it in reality, but using the form makes it seem gentler, less abrupt.

It's possible that this is a regional difference: I speak British English.

Comment: I'll admit my comment was lazy and imprecise.  There's nothing wrong with "will be closing" as I hear it all the time, e.g. *"The store will be closing in 15 minutes, please make your final purchases."*   However, this context is for a *temporary* closure, not a permanent closure.  To say a business *will be permanently closing*, especially combined with *from* some specified time, feels odd, as if the writer wasn't sure what he wanted to say.   Perhaps it reflects his own mixed feelings on the closure.

Comment: no Rhythm has been  a mail orderd situated in Cambridge England where people are supposed to speak a very good english

Comment: @Andrew, I still don't find it odd. As I say, I think it is meant (not necessarily consciously) to soften the blow.

Comment: @user5577: I'm not sure who is doing the supposing, but there is no reason why people in Cambridge should speak "a very good English" (whatever that might mean) compared to anywhere else.

Comment: because of the Cambridge university which is very famous

Comment: @user5577: Yes, I guessed that might be what you meant. But it really doesn't follow, that people will speak a certain way just because they happen to be in a city with a famous university.

Comment: In a way, it's typical British "underspeak" and I agree would soften the blow, so to speak. [speak very good English, by the way, no a]